# TokenInput does not handle plus sign well

Tags: jquery

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5UB8c/)

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="token-input-facebook.css" />
<script src="jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<br/><label for="ExpFilter">Expl:</label><br/>
<input type="text"  id="ExpFilter" style="width:100px"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var Code_Expl = [
{ id: 0, name:"+ DESIGNATED CONTRACTING STATES:"},
{ id: 1, name:"+ EXTENSION OF THE EUROPEAN PATENT TO"},
{ id: 2, name:"+ REQUEST FOR EXAMINATION FILED"},
{ id: 3, name:"+ PAYMENT OF DESIGNATION FEES"},
{ id: 4, name:"+ FIRST EXAMINATION REPORT"},
{ id: 5, name:"- LAPSED IN A CONTRACTI...FROM NAT. OFFICE TO EPO"},
{ id: 6, name:"+ EUROPEAN PATENT GRANTED"},
{ id: 7, name:"+ ENTRY IN THE NATIONAL PHASE"},
{ id: 8, name:"BE: CHANGE OF HOLDER'S NAME"},
{ id: 9, name:"CORRESPONDS TO:"},
{ id:10, name:"+ EUROPEAN PATENTS GRANTED DESIGNATING IRELAND"},
{ id:11, name:"- PATENT CEASED"},
{ id:12, name:"- FR: TRANSLATION NOT FILED"},
{ id:13, name:"+ NO OPPOSITION FILED"},
{ id:14, name:"- PATENT LAPSED"},
{ id:15, name:"+ POSTGRANT: ANNUAL FEES PAID TO NATIONAL OFFICE"},
{ id:16, name:"- BE: LAPSED"},
{ id:17, name:"- GB: EUROPEAN PATENT C...-PAYMENT OF RENEWAL FEE"}
];
```

WORKS:

```
var query = "+ DE";  
var results = $.grep(Code_Expl, function (row) {
  return row.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});
console.log(results);  
// ---------------------
```

WORKS, But not for content starting with PLUS - Why? I use the same grep above
It seems to be the populate function that fails but I cannot see why

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ExpFilter").tokenInput(Code_Expl,{theme: "facebook"});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was fixed six months ago in a commit on github:

https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/314

Just download the master from github instead of from the website, and you'll be fine. Had the same problem on my own site with the category "C++".

Answer (score 1):

As must I understand that the problem is within in regular expression of these two functions.

```
    function highlight_term(value, term) {
        return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + term + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<b>$1</b>");
    }

    function find_value_and_highlight_term(template, value, term) {
        return template.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]+)(" + value + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "g"), highlight_term(value, term));
    }
```

You have to modify this regEx to get your desired output.

Comment: Would you have a suggestion what to modify and why it did this to begin with? - URL decoding?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Just replace the + charachters with &#43 unicode :)